# 5 minutes and 10 seconds before given time

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime

I need to figure out

- 5 minutes before given time
- 10 seconds before given time
  I have try this code

  ```
  echo $time.'<br />'; 
  echo 'fivemin'.$fivemin= date("H:m:s",strtotime("-5 minutes",strtotime($time))); 
  echo '<br />tensec'.$tensec=$datetime_from = date("H:m:s",strtotime("-10 seconds",strtotime($time)));
  ```

**result**

```
15:55:44
fivemin 15:04:44
tensec 15:04:34
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [DateTime::sub](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php) method for this.

```
// Set the initial date/time
$date = new DateTime('2015-04-03 12:00:00');

// Go back 5 minutes
$date->sub(new DateInterval('PT5M'));

// $date is now 2015-04-03 11:55:00, go back another 10 seconds...
$date->sub(new DateInterval('PT10S'));
```

You can also combine the two subs into one (I just split them so you have a better idea of what's going on and you may want to run some actions in between the subs):

```
$date->sub(new DateInterval('PT5M10S')); // 5 minutes and 10 seconds ago
```

That will subtract 5 minutes and 10 seconds in 1 go.

You will then end up with `$date` being a DateTime object, that is now representing 2015-04-03 11:54:50.